# How do I get the enter the marks into a text field and get it to calculate the average?

Tags: javascript

[Screenshot of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VVcn.png)

The above is the question.

So far I have only been able using push function... I would appreciate some help in learning how to make it possible to have a text field and enter the marks into it and press the button so the code will take it and calculate it to the average.

FYI. this is an external.js.

```
// JavaScript Document
function button() {
var marks;
marks = [43, 54, 84, 70, 96];


marks.push(62);
marks.push(55);
marks.push(86);
marks.push(50);
marks.push(76);



var results;
results = ((marks[0] + marks[1] + marks[2] + marks[3] + marks[4] + marks[5] + marks[6] + marks[7] + marks[8] + marks[9]) / 10)

document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = ("Students mark : " + marks);
document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = ("The average mark is : " + results);
}
```

Comment: Please add more code what did you tried and what error you faced to get a better response!

Comment: All I did was made an HTML that is linked to the  .js and has a button and id linked to the getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of the input element above you just need to use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

I think it answers your question:

HTML Part:

```
<input type="text" id="nums">
<button onclick="getAvg()">
Get Average
</button>
```

JS Part:

```
function getAvg(){
    var nums = document.getElementById("nums").value;
  console.log(nums);

  var arr = nums.split(',')
  console.log(arr);

  average = arr.reduce(function (avg, value, _, { length }) {
        return avg + parseInt(value) / length;
    }, 0);
  console.log(average);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for you: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/bc2yskan/20/

**Short and Quick Way JS:**

```
// JavaScript Document
function button() {
    var marks;
    marks = [43, 54, 84, 70, 96];

    var enter_marks = document.getElementById ("new_marks");

    if (enter_marks.value){
          marks.push(parseInt(enter_marks.value));
     }

    marks.push(62);
    marks.push(55);
    marks.push(86);
    marks.push(50);
    marks.push(76);

  //Total
   var results = marks.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
   var average = results / 10;

    document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = ("Students mark : " + marks);
    document.getElementById("total_marks").innerHTML = ("Total marks : " + results);
    document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = ("The average mark is : " + average);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="num1"></div>
<br>
<div id="num2"></div>
<br>
<div id="total_marks"></div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" id="new_marks" placeholder="Enter New Marks"/>
<button class="calculate_average" onclick="button()">Calculate Average</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code, the first 10 marks are added on load.
And you can enter a new mark, and the average will be recalculated.

```js
var marks;
  var results;

  var new_mark = document.getElementById ("new_mark");

  window.addEventListener ("load", function (e){

   marks = [43, 54, 84, 70, 96];

   marks.push(62);
   marks.push(55);
   marks.push(86);
   marks.push(50);
   marks.push(76);

   results = ((marks[0] + marks[1] + marks[2] + marks[3] + marks[4] + marks[5] + marks[6] + marks[7] + marks[8] + marks[9]) / 10)

   document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = ("Students mark : " + marks);
   document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = ("The average mark is : " + results);
  });

  function NewMarkClicked() {
   if (new_mark.value){
    marks.push (new_mark.value);
   }


   results = 0 ;         

   for (var i = 0 ; i < marks.length ; i ++ ){
     results += parseInt (marks[i]);
   }
   results = (results / marks.length).toFixed (2);;

   document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = ("Students mark : " + 
   marks);
   document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = ("The average mark is : " + 
   results);
  }
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <textarea id ="num1">
 </textarea>

 <br>

 <div id ="num2"></div>

 <br><br>

 <input type="text" id="new_mark"><br>
 <button onclick="NewMarkClicked ()">Enter new mark </button>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @UsmanMunir You should parse the marks as an integer when adding It the the results in the `NewMarkClicked` function. Check again after the update, It is calculating the average correctly.

Comment: Yes you should parseInt. Thanks for fixing your code.

Comment: @UsmanMunir  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking on the big gray check button on its left side. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by clicking on the upper gray triangle

Comment: this question was not asked by me. Apologies. Please check.